# calling web service from windows mobile

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

can any one help me with example about the steps of calling public web services for windows mobile 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very, very broad.  What kind of web service [XML/SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx)?  [WCF](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/11/29/an-introduction-to-wcf-for-device-developers.aspx)? [REST](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html)? Public APIs like [Facebook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932386.aspx) or [Twitter](http://ntwitter.codeplex.com/)? Refine the question and we might be able to refine the answer.

Comment: So just add a Web Reference to it, which will generate the proxy classes like in the first link in my list.